# How Can I Get Name Attribute In React

Tags: reactjs

I need to get name atribute in button element. I can get it from DOM but I dont want to do that. If there is a easy way to get name atribute please help me. ( I use functional Component )

`<button name="elementsName"> elementsName <button/>`

Comment: You didn't include enough code to make your issue clear. When do you want to get this name attribute?

Comment: I want to get it at first render

Comment: At the first render, the button doesn't even exist yet. I guess that you want to use that information in click handler or something like that

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hook call **useRef** to access element properties.

Read more about [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

**Solution:**

Simply create **useRef** in your component and **bind** it with your button and access its properties

**Example:**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const App = ({ ...props }) => {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null); 
  const hanldeGetButtonRef = () => {
    console.log("button REF ==>", buttonRef.current.name);
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={hanldeGetButtonRef}>
      <button name="elementsName" ref={buttonRef}>
        CLICK
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```